# How to properly use modify-syntax-entry flags to syntax highlight comments in Lua?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, comment

I made my own Lua major mode about a month back. There is one thing that is still not working:
highlighting comments.

At first, I simply added `("--.*" . font-lock-comment-face)` to `lua-font-lock-keywords`.
That works but whenever there are quotes `"like this"` in the comment, the comment is no longer coloured.
This observation has been made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099970/how-do-i-ensure-the-correct-precedence-in-emacs-highlighting-keywords/24100595#24100595). The recommendation on the answer is to change the syntax table. Okay.

So, I need `modify-syntax-entry`, yes?
My first attempt was the following:

```lisp
    (defun fix-comments ()
        (modify-syntax-entry ?- "<12")
        (modify-syntax-entry ?\n ">"))
```

and of course a hook.

```
    (add-hook 'lua-mode-hook 'fix-comments)
```

This does colour comments even when there are double-quotes. That's good.
But it starts comment at `-` instead of at `--`

The documentation says the following: `Any additional characters are flags.` and:

> 1 means `CHAR` is the start of a two-char comment start sequence.
> 2 means `CHAR` is the second character of such a sequence."

I am not sure how to interpret this other than `<12`. But that doesn't work.

So, how do I get `--` to properly colour a comment start?

EDIT:
An answer can be found [here](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/elisp_comment_coloring.html). C++ comments are basically the same but they use forward slash instead of a dash. Here's the answer which works:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?- ". 12b")
(modify-syntax-entry ?\n "> b")
```

However, I still don't understand how it works. Why did they use a `.` instead of `<`? Why do you need the whitespace? What does the b, c and n flags do (I don't understand the documentation for these)?